Автозапуск Python-скриптов в JupyterLab
Работаю на сервере Hadoop, в JupyterLab запускаю Python-скрипты содержащие Spark-сессию и sql запросы к БД (реплики).
Вопрос: как можно автоматизировать запуск определённых скриптов по расписанию.
Доступен стандартный инструментарий HUE, JupyterLab, Планировщик Windows/
Не знаю как запускать свои скрипты в автоматическом режиме, приходится заходить и тыкать ручками..
Может кто-то помочь?

Jupiter по определению вещь интерактивная. Вызывай из планировщика spark-submit ... /path/to/my_script.py, а в скрипте д.б. всё то, что у тебя в Юпитере
